# 'which qmake' returns value, but 'sudo which qmake' does not

Tags: sudo, path

So I am trying to install a program, gnuradio, in my /opt folder.  In order to install it, I need to execute my commands as sudo.  When installing, I get the following error: `/bin/sh: qmake: command not found`

When I type `which qmake` I get: `/usr/lib64/qt4/bin/qmake`

However, when I run `sudo which qmake` I get: `which: no qmake in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)`

I've looked at various fixes, but I don't think they address the same issue that I am having.  The closest guide I could find to my issue is [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597487/qmake-not-found-although-qt-installed).

For your reference, I'm on RHEL7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because sudo only runs within `secure_path` defined at `/etc/sudoers` or `$PATH` set for sudo. For example, in my system,

```
$ sudo env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers | grep secure_path
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
```

So, you've couple of work-arounds:

1. Either make a link of `/usr/lib64/qt4/bin/qmake` to one of the `secure_path` i.e something like:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/qt4/bin/qmake /usr/bin/qmake
   ```
2. Or add `/usr/lib64/qt4/bin` in `/etc/sudoers` as follows:

   ```
   Defaults    secure_path="sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib64/qt4/bin"
   ```

   In above line keep other text as it is, only add your path `/usr/lib64/qt4/bin` at the end as exampled.

Comment: Defaults is not found as a RHEL bash command.

Comment: what's the output of `sudo cat /etc/sudoers | grep secure_path` ?

Comment: `Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` I'm going to eat my words a lot I see

Comment: @ajsmart you can modify `/etc/sudoers` by `visudo` or any other text editor like `gedit` as a root user.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons that should be obvious, your `PATH` is not inherited by the privileges shell in which `sudo` executes its commands.  You can alleviate this by providing the full path to `qmake` (e. g. `sudo $(which qmake)`) or by putting your call to `qmake` into a script which sets its own `PATH`, and which you invoke with `sudo /path/to/my/qmake-script.sh`.

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear, the qmake is being called by python, is there a way to add the path permanently to sudo qmake?

Comment: The python script should similarly handle its own `PATH` for its `os.system()` execution environment.

Comment: well, at the heart of the problem, i run `pybombs install gnuradio`, and i don't have permissions, but DO have qmake.  when I run `sudo install gnuradio` I have the permissions, but not qmake.  I guess I'm just not understanding how the paths are different with sudo.

Comment: Try `sudo pybombs install gnuradio` perhaps?  I imagine that `pybombs` is a wrapper script that might handle the `PATH` management.

Comment: typo, `sudo pybombs install gnuradio` has permissions, but not qmake.  I typed it wrong.

Comment: is it possible that its path management is derived from whether or not I run it as sudo?